# Why is my 2d OnCollisionEnter not working unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am relatively new to Unity and am working on kind of a 'starter game' to get situated, just a 2D platformer.
I wrote this code to detect collisions:

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Ground/Floor")
    {
        
        Debug.Log("touched floor");
    }
}
```

However, when my character(what this script is on) collides with the Tilemap(which has the tag Ground/Floor), it does not log the message. Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: For 3d collisions, a rigidbody is required on at least one of the objects.  I imagine it is the same for 2d collisions, though the scripting reference does not mention it.  Try adding the Rigidbody2D component to your player object.  You will need to change settings to suit your projects needs.

Comment: I have the Rigidybody2D on both components

Comment: Is your script on the same object the collider component is on?  Have you confirmed the function does not fire by putting a debug lot outside of your condition?

Comment: in general rather use `if(collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Ground/Floor"))` just to rule out any silently hidden typo ...

Comment: Also the object I am trying to collide with is a tilemap with a composite collider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. I accidentally created the ground/floor tag but hadn't assigned it to the tilemap. Sorry for the confusion.